# How to get the animation I want?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I wanted to make some tests. I thought, let's make an animation for a cell in a `UITableView` such as: it goes from the normal size, expand horizontally a bit over the normal size, reduce horizontally a bit under the normal size and go back to the normal size. So I thought make this:

```
let width = cell.frame.size.width

cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, cell.frame.origin.y, width, cell.frame.size.height)

UIView.animateWithDuration(4.25, animations: {
    cell.frame = CGRectMake(width * -1/8, cell.frame.origin.y, width * 5/4, cell.frame.size.height)
    }, completion: { finished in
        UIView.animateWithDuration(2.5, animations: {
            cell.frame = CGRectMake(width * 1/8, cell.frame.origin.y, width * 3/4, cell.frame.size.height)
            }, completion: { finished in
                UIView.animateWithDuration(1.25) {
                    cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, cell.frame.origin.y, width, cell.frame.size.height)
                }
        })
})
```

Use animations and completions in cascades. The problem is at the beginning. The frame reduces quickly horizontally (instead of expanding) then slowly (4.25 seconds) expands to the normal size. Then it reduces and then expand back to normal as expected.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Well, this is a mess.

Comment: I'm not asking here if it looks good or not as it is a test (as I said). Instead of just saying it is a mess, maybe you could enlighten me a bit more and tell me how you would do it less "messy" or just explain me why I get this result.

Comment: You should learn how to declare blocks instead of inlining them, then unwind all of this code and use actual block variables.  Then the problem will probably become quite obvious.

Comment: Why not use spring animation?

Comment: Didn't think about spring animation, I'll have a look thanks. @nhgrif what do you mean by blocks? Do you mean like Kelvin Lau used (`animateKeyframesWithDuration`)? I still don't have any idea why it behaves like this and I'm not sure it will become quite obvious using blocks. Feel free to give me some example, it would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was actually fiddling with animations just like the one you were doing just now :)

You can do the horizontal effect much easier; Instead of redefining the frame itself, you can simply adjust the horizontal bounds of the cell:

```
cell.bounds.size.width += 30 //grow it horizontally by 30 points
```

There's also a much more succinct method in dealing with this problem: `UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(_ delay: options: animations: completion:)`

With animateKeyframes, you can string a list of different animation effects in order, which is what you want. I'll start you off:

```
UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(4.0, delay: 0.0, options: nil, animations: { 
    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.0, relativeDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.cell.bounds.size.width += 30
    })
    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(2.5, relativeDuration: 0.1, animations: {
        self.cell.bounds.size.width -= 60
    })
    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(3.0, relativeDuration: 0.1, animations: {
        self.cell.bounds.size.width += 30
    })
}, completion: nil)
```

To put it simply, you define a duration for which the animation will occur. For the above code sample, I've defined 4 seconds.

Within the 4 seconds, I defined 3 different animations, specifying at what time they should fire off, and how long they should be fired for (relativeDuration, which is relative to the 4.0 second value).

Adjusting those numbers will allow you to customize the timings.

Hope that works!

Comment: Do you know why the width of the frame doesn't change when I do like this and instead it's the whole frame that is moving, keeping the same length?

Comment: perhaps change the animation statement `self.cell.bounds.size.width` to `self.cell.frame.size.width`. I thought my version would have worked o.o